# RSpec - Do I need to keep non-request specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have generated a few controllers and models to my app and now I want to add testing (I know it's a little backwards but at least I am starting fairly early in my project).  Anyway, every time I generated a controller/model I did not include the --no-test-framework so now I have a bunch of specs related to controllers, helpers, models, and views.  Do I need these?  And, if not, is it okay to just delete them?  I am noticing from some tutorials (Hartl, Bates) that they are using request specs, are these all I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can delete which ever specs you feel you don't need/want.
More often than not, I remove the helpers/views specs.
I wouldn't suggest just doing request specs if you want a thorough testing suite.

Comment: @veritas1 - Thanks for your helpful answer.  By the way, why use request specs?  What's the difference between request specs and all the others?

Comment: This link will give you a better understanding of the specs and the role they play - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11/docs

Comment: Great resource. Thanks again.